# CLGeocoder usage to return city string?

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to make a http request using a string made up of a URL and a city name, using CLGeocoder to get the current location of the user and then to return the name of the city they're in. The string is made before the call is made, and is concatenated using the `+` operator. Using placeMark.locality isn't returning the city name correctly, is there a better way to get the city name from a location?

Here is the basic layout of my string URL:

```
"https://domain.com/search/text/city=" + placeMark.locality!
```

Comment: "Using placeMark.locality isn't returning the city name correctly" What _is_ it doing?

Comment: It's causing my http request to fail, whereas when I simply write the whole string and manually type a city it works perfectly

Comment: And why is that? What's the value of `placeMark.locality` that is giving you a bad http request? Come on, try to give some _information_ about what the problem is.

Comment: Will check that out when I get back to it in the morning, thanks for the quick replies! I've a sneaking suspicion that it's either not returning a valid string, or it's returning a string that, when put into a URL, isn't formatted correctly for the URL. So say it's Los Angeles, it should be los%20angeles, but I'll know for sure when I'm back at it tomorrow. Think I just needed to write the problem out to get myself thinking but thanks!

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like the problem is that you are just "adding" the city with a `+`. That is not going to get you a valid URL!

Comment: So am I right in thinking that I'll need a do/while loop to find all the spaces in the locality and replace them with %20, then store the result as a new var?

Comment: No you are not. URLComponents will do all the work of forming a valid URL given the parts.

Comment: Just seen your answer, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one: never, never, never try to form a URL as a string, like what you're doing:

```
"https://domain.com/search/text/city=" + placeMark.locality!
```

To form a URL, *form* the URL, using [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents). That is what they are for!

Answer (score 0):

sometime placeMark.locality is empty , but you can use placeMark.administrativeArea